# unzipping downloaded zip repo from remote repository before saving in browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I download a zip file from remote repo. Now I want to unzip that before saving to local system. How to do that in browser itself  ? No need to unzip explicitly outside of browser

Comment: Hello Danish, what have you tried so far? Are you looking to do this in code? Without further details, the question cannot be answered I'm afraid. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library like [JSZip](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip) or [fflate](https://github.com/101arrowz/fflate) to unzip in the browser. You download the file, unzip, and save. Since `fflate` is faster, I'll use it.

```js
const downloadFilesFromZip = async url => {
  console.log('Downloading from ' + url + '...');
  const unzipper = new fflate.Unzip();
  unzipper.register(fflate.AsyncUnzipInflate);
  unzipper.onfile = file => {
    console.log("Got", file.name);
    if (file.originalSize) {
      console.log("Original size:", file.originalSize);
    }
    const rs = new ReadableStream({
      start(controller) {
        file.ondata = (err, dat, final) => {
          controller.enqueue(dat);
          if (final) controller.close();
        }
        file.start();
      }
    });
    streamSaver.createWriteStream(
      file.name,
      rs
    );
  }
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const reader = res.body.getReader();
  while (true) {
    const { value, done } = await reader.read();
    if (done) {
      unzipper.push(new Uint8Array(0), true);
      break;
    }
    unzipper.push(value);
  }
}
// Call downloadFilesFromZip to download all files from a URL
// downloadFilesFromZip('https://your-url.com/file.zip');
downloadFilesFromZip(
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + 
  'https://github.com/101arrowz/fflate/archive/master.zip'
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/streamsaver@2.0.3/StreamSaver.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fflate@0.6.4/umd/index.js"></script>
```

StackOverflow doesn't allow downloads from answers, so it doesn't work properly, but the console will show the files that `fflate` found. Also, you need to go to [this link](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/corsdemo) and allow access before running that snippet.